# Check if any number in one hash is present in another hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm working with two hashes. One hash includes all products for which a user has an active subscription. The second is a hash of all valid possible products.

- `userProducts`:

  ```
  {0=>"4", 1=>"50"}
  ```
- `validProducts`:

  ```
  {"79.00 Annually"=>22, "Developer"=>23, "Owner"=>4, "Editor + Forum Moderator"=>5, "8.99 Monthly"=>9, "21.58 Quarterly"=>10, "Tracker"=>14,   "One Month"=>25, "Insider PRO Upgrade"=>38, "Insider Alert Sender"=>39, ""One Year"=>33, "Three Months"=>34, "Forum Admin"=>40, }
  ```

I need to check if the user product hash overlaps with the valid products hash.

I'm trying like this:

```
<% userProducts.each do |up|  %>
    <% if validProducts.any? { |product| product.include?(up[1]) } %>
        OK
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

but nothing is getting me where I need to go.

The end goal is to write an attribute to `current_user` that indicates they have a payment method on file. I'm starting by printing `"OK"` to the screen so I can be sure the condition is met, before trying to write data to the DB.

Comment: Your `validProducts` is invalid.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by overlap. Do you mean a common key-value pair? If so, your two hashes look too different, and they obviously do not have overlaps. Or, even if you mean only common keys, or common values, the situation is the same. They obviously do not overlap.

Comment: So in the User hash, the user has products ID 4 and 50.  In validProducts, there is "Owner"=>4.   That's the match I'm trying to make, for example.

Comment: No, the first hash doesn't have `4` and `50`. It has `"4"` and `"50"`. And as I already wrote (which you seem to be ignoring), your second "hash" is not even a hash.

Comment: Not ignoring, just confused.  I'm not entirely sure what's going on here.  What is the difference in Ruby between "4" and 4?  String vs Integer?    If my second object isn't a hash, what is it?

Comment: 1. String vs Integer?--Yes.  2. If my second object isn't a hash, what is it?--Actually, it is not an object. As I have already written, it it invalid. It is not anything in Ruby.

Comment: Your second hash has an extra `"` which is causing it to break.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to check if the value of a specific userProduct matches any value of the validProducts:

```
<% userProducts.each do |up|  %>
  <% if validProducts.any? %>
      puts "OK" if validProducts.values.include(up[1].to_i)
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Note that one set of values are integers and the other are strings, thus the `.to_i`.

I'd avoid doing this in a view if I could.

Answer (score 0):

Look for an intersection in the set of values for the hashes:

```
!(userProducts.values.map{|v| v.to_i} & validProducts.values).empty?
```

Edit: added conversion of userProducts values to_i.